# How to create Custom CrytalReporting Template and save File to PDF using VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, pdf, crystal-reports, reporting

[image: I Want to create report like this Form picture]

i want to create report like that picture but i dont know to implement in VB.Net
im using VS 2012.

i had Form before that show tabel SMS and Device Details in DataGridview, and one button to show AS report

can anyone help me to create report like that, and save the report AS PDF

For tables "Identitas Telepone" i get the data From My database that named tb_identitas (SELECT * FROM tb_identitas WHERE serialno = 'Textbox3'), and tables "Barang Bukti SMS" i want to get the data from my Db Tables  that named tb_sms (SELECT * FROM tb_sms where id = 'e.g')

i using mysql

somebody help me please....

Comment: This is not a jobs board. You cannot recruit people on SO to do your work for you. If you have a *specific* programming related question, ask it, and hopefully someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Custom can be done at your query nothing else..
I suggest create a crystal report using command (In crystal report connection wizard). then open the command and paste the query you want on it. you can paste it multiple query in there to make your report more complicated.

[image]

Inside the command is your query.